# Align columns in bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm trying to achieve two fixed columns in Bootstrap. Current situation is you can see on the image below:

[image]

I'm trying to achieve that left and right column is align to the top no matter how many item I have in column. See image below.

[image]

My current code is here:

```
[3]:https://jsfiddle.net/evr86bjn/2/
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Remove      align-items: center;  for holder css

Comment: Please include relevant code snippets in your question as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You gave align-items: center for the Holder div. Try adding align-items:flex-start. hope this will fix the issue.

```
.Holder {
display: flex;
align-items: flex-start;
justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

remove `align-items: center;` from `.holder`. since 1st ul has less content it is aligned to center.

https://jsfiddle.net/evr86bjn/2/

```
    .Holder {
    display: flex;
    /* align-items: center; */
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap at your own advantage if you want...
I stripped down your html code to just your 2 ul, using bootstrap its quite simple, something like

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">             
    <ul id="listWrap" class="price-table__info"> 
      <li>
        <p class="ocjenaNaslov">Lorem Lorem 1</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p class="rok1">Lorem lorem 1</p>
        <p>Lorem lorem</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p class="rok1">Lorem lorem</p>
        <p>Lorem lorem</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p class="rok1">Lorem lorem</p>
        <p>Lorem lorem</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p class="rok1">Lorem lorem</p>
        <p>2</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <ul id="listWrap" class="price-table__info">
      <li>
        <p class="ocjenaNaslov">Lorem Lorem 2</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p class="rok1">Lorem lorem</p>
        <p>Lorem lorem</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p class="rok1">Lorem lorem</p>
        <p>Lorem lorem</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p class="rok1">Lorem lorem</p>
        <p>Lorem lorem</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p class="rok1">Lorem lorem</p>
        <p>Lorem lorem</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p class="rok1">Lorem lorem</p>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary waves-effect isp"><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i>Info</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```